# Conjecture on bounding probabilities

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

For an integer $m\geq 1$, consider the $m$th root of unity $\omega:=\exp(2\pi\mathrm i/m)$, and let $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,m\}$. Let $X_i$($i\in I$) be independent real random variables with mean $0$ and finite variance. For a bound $\alpha>0$, consider the events
$$A:=\left\{\left|\sum_{i\in I}X_i\omega^i\right|>\alpha\right\},\qquad B:=\left\{\left|\sum_{i\in I}X_i\right|>\alpha\right\}.$$

Is it necessarily true than $\mathbb P(A)\leq\mathbb P(B)$? It feels intuitive: In $A$, the terms in the sum also have a component in the imaginary direction, while the terms in the sum in $B$ only move into the real direction. So $\sum X_i$ can potentially grow much larger than $\sum X_i\omega^i$.

I am also fine with adding some assumption, e.g. that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. (not just independent).

---

Note that it is not true that $A\subseteq B$. For instance, if $m=2$ and $I=\{1,2\}$, then we could have $X_1=1,X_2=-1$, so that

$$\sum_{i\in I}X_i\omega^i=2,\qquad\sum_{i\in I}X_i=0.$$

---

To get a feeling, it may be easiest to start with a special case. Namely, to (dis)prove that
$$\mathbb P(|X+\mathrm iY|>\alpha)\leq \mathbb P(|X+Y|>\alpha),$$

where $\alpha>0$ and $X,Y$ are independent random variables with mean $0$ and finite variance. Equivalently,

$$\mathbb P(X^2+Y^2>\alpha)\leq \mathbb P(X^2+2XY+Y^2>\alpha)$$

for $\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Take $m=4$ and let $X_i$ be symmetric Rademacher variables, i.e. $P(X_i = \pm 1) = 1/2$. Then$^*$,  $X:= \sum_{i\in I} X_i = Y_1+Y_2$, $X_o:= \sum_{i\in I} X_i o_i = Y_1 + \mathrm{i}\,Y_2$, where $Y_1$ and iid with $\mathrm P(Y_i=\pm 2)=\frac14$, $\mathrm P(Y_i=\pm 0)=\frac12$. Obviously, $\mathrm P(X=0) = \frac{3}{8} > \mathrm P(X_o=0) = \frac{1}{4}$, so $\mathrm P(|X|>0) < \mathrm P(|X_o|>0)$.

---

$^*$ I changed $\omega_i$ to $o_i$, since $\omega$ denotes a random outcome.