# Complex normal variable vs. real normal variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $Z\sim\mathcal N_{\mathbb C}(0,1)$ be a complex normal variable, that is
$$Z=V+\mathrm iW,$$
where $V,W\sim\mathcal N_{\mathbb R}(0,1/2)$ are independent real normal variables. Consider further a real normal variable $X\sim \mathcal N_{\mathbb R}(0,1)$.

For a bound $\alpha>0$, is it always true that
$$\mathbb P(|Z|>\alpha)\leq P(|X|>\alpha)?$$

---

This is my try to save the conjecture that I proposed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4654895/730592) post (which turned out to be wrong).
It turns out that one can (using heuristic arguments) go from the situation in the linked problem to the one presented here.

---

As in the other question, we can equivalently try to prove
$$\mathbb P(V^2+W^2>\alpha)\leq \mathbb P(X^2>\alpha).$$
It is not hard to see that the left-hand side is *at least* half of the right-hand side, but this of course does not help.

Also, using convolutions seems a little overkill here (I am frankly not even sure if it would lead to anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only looking at the magnitude, the complex part of this drops out completely and you're just left with a $\chi^2$ distribution, $k=1,2$.

This reduces to a mechanical verification that $\chi^2_1$ dominates $\frac{1}{2}\chi^2_2$ in CDF. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) gives the CDF as
$$F(x;k)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\gamma\left(\frac{k}{2},\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
and in fact the special form $F(x;2)=1-e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$.

A cursory look at the plot of the CDFs show that your conjecture here is wrong. [Wolfram plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1-e%5E%28-x%29%2CIncompleteGamma%5B0.5%2Cx%2F2%5D%2FGamma%5B0.5%5D+for+x%3D0+to+5).